# Blob event grid trigger filters with regular expression

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I have added an event grid trigger for blobs created in Azure Storage. I'm trying to filter the events using subject filter in event grid. I'm able to specify the "subject starts with" condition in the filter. But few temporary files gets created in the same path with random file name. I want to filter events for such temp files. Is it possible to achieve something like subject starts with "/blobServices/default/containers/Name/blobs/*/test_*". so that only events for files whose name starts with "test" are sent out

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard in the Azure Event Grid filtering is not supported. However, if your file name prefix is unique (no name of the container or subdirectory) such as **test_** in your case, the advanced filtering can be used it, see following example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @RomanKiss for your comment. As I cannot have control over all files created in the container,  it might not work.

Comment: Also, the last empty subdirector can be helped to make a unique filtering on the prefix of the filename, such as **//test_**, otherwise the subscriber needs to handle this filtering or *Azure API Management*.

Comment: I didn't get that. Could you please explain what do you meant by last empty subdirectory ?

Comment: example of filepath: /blobServices/default/containers/Name/blobs/*//test_*